# Nested sorting for predefined filters using LINQ and RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I had problems for appropriate title for this question because I have interesting sorting issue I want to solve.

So, I defined 3 objects of type `user { skill: level }`:

```
a { s1: 1, s2: 2, s3: 4 }
b { s1: 2, s2: 2, s3: 4 }
c { s1: 1, s2: 5, s3: 9 }
```

Now I want to sort the users `a`, `b` and `c` by sum of chosen skills. The selects skills are `s1` and `s2`. I don't care about `s3`.

The ordered result for filter `[s1,s2]` should be `[c,b,a]` because

```
s1 + s2 for c = 6, 
            b = 4, 
            a = 3
```

I have defined classes for that case:

```
class Skill
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Skill> Skills { get; set; }            
}
```

and initialized it:

```
var a = new User
            {
                    Name = "a",
                    Skills = new List<Skill>
                                {
                                    new Skill {Name = "s1", Level = 1},
                                    new Skill {Name = "s2", Level = 2},
                                    new Skill {Name = "s3", Level = 4}
                                }
                };
var b = new User
            {
                    Name = "b",
                    Skills = new List<Skill>
                                {
                                    new Skill {Name = "s1", Level = 2},
                                    new Skill {Name = "s2", Level = 2},                                              
                                    new Skill {Name = "s3", Level = 4}
                                }
                };
var c = new User
            {
                Name = "c",
                Skills = new List<Skill>
                                {
                                    new Skill {Name = "s1", Level = 1},
                                    new Skill {Name = "s2", Level = 5},
                                    new Skill {Name = "s3", Level = 9}
                                }
            };
```

below I have list of users and list of skills I want to use for sorting:

```
var users = new List<User> {a, b, c};
var filters = new List<string> { "s1", "s2" };
```

I want to receive

```
var selected = users.Magic(); // which results in [c,b,a]
```

I want to do this using linq and ravendb. Obviously I do not want to load all data from database into memory, and then do the magic sorting kind of stuff. I suppose I need to create some crazy indexes with map reduce, then some linq queries on such indexes and so on... help ?

Btw: I'm using RavenDB - Build #960

**EDIT:**

My temporary workaround is, unfortunately, read all users data into memory and use linq-to-objects (because of problems related to raven linq driver, which does not support computation during the query):

```
var selected = users.OrderByDescending(user =>
                                user.Skills
                                    .Where(skill => filters.Contains(skill.Name))
                                    .Select(skill => skill.Level)
                                    .Sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = users.OrderBy(user => 
    user.Skills
    .Where(skill => skill.Name == "s1" || skill.Name == "s2")
    .Select(skill => skill.Level)
    .Sum());
```

Comment: Thanks, its correct while I have objects but while I want to fetch results using raven linq driver I get error because "RavenDB doesn't allow computation during the query, computation is only allowed during index. Consider moving the operation to an index."

Answer (score 0):

Create an index that does this summation at indexing time and expose the result

```
from user in docs.Users
select new
{
    Skills_Sum = user.Skills.Sum(x=>x.Level)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about such index but I have to take under consideration sum of random skills the user actually needs, not sum of all skills. Do I need to create combinations of all the sums in some way ? My temporary solution is loading data into memory and usage of linq-to-objects expression similar to that shown by Servy.